# How to get bibliography in the citation order using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I am using the following comments to create the reference list in my notes.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}
%\DeclareFieldFormat{entrykey}{\ttfamily[#1]}
%\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\printfield{entrykey}\setunit{\addspace}} %for the entrykey in bibliography instead of numbers uncomment it
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}  



\begin{document}


First reference is \cite{berman1974inverses}.. And the second reference is this \cite{lang2002algebra}. etc...

But I want the reference list has to be in the citation order. Thats bermans book has to be the first reference as I have cited in my content, and the second has be lang's.

\printbibliography[title=works cited, category=cited]
\end{document}
```

### Question:

> How to get the reference list in the order that I have cited?

My output is,

[image]

### Note:

I am having a database for a bibliography entries. That can be [found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6B5kp_Rfxp-ODNTLUpBV2tYMUk/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Remove `\nocite{*}` and/or `defernumbers=true` ? Note that in effect, you have cited everything before `\begin{document}` as things are now. Or, rather, you've added everything to the bibliography before `\begin{document}` and that's determining the numbers. The order of second use is irrelevant: it is just reusing the existing numbers. Note that you should please post a complete example here including sample bib entries, if required. Or use one of the standard `.bib` files as you prefer.

Comment: I could not understand your comment..Kindly elaborate.@cfr

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what more to say. If you post a complete minimal example, it is possible to demonstrate which is generally easier. If you don't want to do that, I can only suggest again removing `\nocite{*}`, which may be the issue.

Comment: I removed `\nocite{*}`. but still I am having the same issue..@cfr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here's a more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}
\begin{document}

  \cite{nussbaum}

  \cite{markey}

  \cite{doody}

  \printbibliography[title=works cited, category=cited]

\end{document}
```

This is complete and reproduces the unwanted behaviour:

[image: sorted references]

It could probably be minimised further, however. I doubt the `\AtEveryBibitem{}` is required to reproduce the issue.

The problem is that `\nocite{*}` adds all entries to the bibliography, which means that the order of citation in the document is irrelevant since works are now being considered for at least the second time.

Removing `\nocite{*}` produces the wanted behaviour:

[image: unsorted references]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
    \clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
}{}
}
\begin{document}

  \cite{nussbaum}

  \cite{markey}

  \cite{doody}

  \printbibliography[title=works cited, category=cited]

\end{document}
```

If removing the `\nocite{*}` doesn't do the trick, then please edit your question to provide a complete minimal example. Right now it depends on getting a database of entries from somewhere else rather than being self-sufficient. Try reproducing with a standard `.bib` or, failing that, include a minimal number of required `.bib` entries in the question.

Comment: Thankyou..and I am having one doubt in the bib entries in the bib file..which is correct for biblatex..whether this @article{somebook, title={title of the book}, author={authorname},journal={journal name}} or @ARTICLE{somebook, TITILE="{title of the book}",AUTHOR={authorname},JOURNAL={journal name}} ...means the captital letters and the quotation marks makes any problem?@cfr

Comment: The capital letters won't matter but don't use quotation marks as well as curly brackets unless you really need them. Personally, I'd stick to curly brackets and double them if necessary. But, in the usual case, `title = {title of book}` is what you want (or `TITLE = ...` or `Title = ...` or `tITlE = ...` etc.).